# Solve trigonometric inequality $ \sin x + \sin^2 x+ \sin^3 x > 0 $

Tags: trigonometry

I have no idea how to start to solve this trigonometric inequality:
$$ \sin x + \sin^2 x+ \sin^3 x > 0 $$

Comment: Look at the polynomial $y+y^2+y^3>0$.  Once you have solved that, you can find when your expression is positive.

Comment: Hint:' multiply by $1-\sin x$ and check separately $\sin x =\pm 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sin x + \sin^2 x+ \sin^3 x=\sin x\cdot (1+\sin x+\sin^2 x)$$
Set $X=\sin x$ and your equation becomes
$$X (1+X+X^2)>0.$$

Comment: So now when $ (X>0  \bigwedge (1 + X + X^2) > 0) \bigvee  (X<0 \bigwedge (1 + X + X^2) < 0)$?

Comment: @Gjekask Yes. Now, $1+X+X^2$ is a quadratic. If it doesn't have any real roots, then it never intersects the $x$-axis, which means that it's either always positive or always negative. Does $1+X+X^2$ have real roots?

Comment: No it didn't have real roots, so I had only to try X>0. Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

Notice
\begin{align*}
\sin x +\sin^2 x+\sin^3 x&=(\sin^2 x+\sin x+1)\sin x\\
&=\left[\left(\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right]\sin x
\end{align*}
Then, since $$\left(\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}>0,$$ we have $$\sin x +\sin^2 x+\sin^3 x>0\iff\sin x >0\iff x\in]0,\pi[\text{ mod }2\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin x \le 1$ for all $x$ implies $\; 1 - \sin x \ge 0$ for all $x$.

Its easy to see that $\; \sin x = 1$ is a solution to $\sin x + \sin^2 x+ \sin^3 x > 0$. So, from this point on, we can assume that $\; \sin x \ne 1$, or equivalently, $1 - \sin x \gt 0$. It also follow that, when $\sin x \ne 1$, then $\; 1 - \sin^3 x \gt 0$, which we will need soon.

So, assuming that $\sin x \ne 1$,

\begin{align}
   \sin x + \sin^2 x+ \sin^3 x > 0
   &\iff 1 + \sin x + \sin^2 x+ \sin^3 x > 1\\
   &\iff (1 - \sin x)(1 + \sin x + \sin^2 x+ \sin^3 x) > 1 - \sin x\\
   &\iff 1 - \sin^4 x > 1 - \sin x\\
   &\iff \sin x - \sin^4 x \gt 0\\
   &\iff \sin x(1 - \sin^3 x) \gt 0\\
   &\iff \sin x \gt 0\\
\end{align}

Note that $\sin x \gt 0$ includes $\sin x = 1$ so we no longer need to treat $ \sin x = 1$ as a special case. So the solution set is

$2n\pi \lt x \lt \pi + 2n\pi$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$

or

$x \in (0,\; \pi) + 2n\pi$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Mario G's answer is the correct way to solve the problem. I just wanted to see if I could solve it this way.